# Calling method of class in hub using SignalR

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have hub class with some methods, which are called by client without problems. But what to do, if I want to call method of class in hub's property, for example:

```
Class MyHub
  Inherits Hub
  Sub HubMethod()
  End Sub
  Property SC As New SimpleClass
End Class

Class SimpleClass
  Sub DoNothing()
  End Sub
End Class
```

I want to do something like `myHubInstance.Invoke("SC.DoNothing")`. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that. SignalR server discovers hubs using Reflection by checking if a type is derived from `IHub`.

Comment: So only possibility is to put methods with same name into hub and call methods of private instance of SimpleClass in hub in these methods?

Comment: You can create a new hub as well and call it directly. Also, note that hub instances are volatile i.e. they are created each time a hub is method is called.

Comment: The problem is that I have data repository and this class have over 20 methods. I am forced to manually copy everything from repository and call that in hub's methods.